# How to pass an extra parameters in SEO friendly urls?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, request

I have a SEO friendly url like this : `/blog/post/15`

But now i want to pass an extra parameter like this:

```
/blog/post/15/?show_comments=1
```

But when i'm trying to access value of parameter 'show_comments' its returning null value.

I'm using follwing rewrite rule in .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^blog/post/([^/\.]+) blog/post.php?id=$1&show_comments=$2 [L]
```

***Note:-*** I don't want to pass extra parameter in url like this /blog/post/15/1

Answer (score 3):

The original query string got replaced with the one you created in your substitution URL.

You need to use the `QSA` flag (Query String Append) here to merge your new parameters with the already existing ones:

```
RewriteRule ^blog/post/([^/\.]+) blog/post.php?id=$1&show_comments=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Yeah Now it's working fine after adding QSA flag.Thank you very much for your support.